# How do I filter an ICollectionView based on the sub property of an item?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to filter by a sub property of the items (Processor objects) in my collection but am unable.  The property is a simple Boolean to indicate if the item is enabled or disabled.  Enabled items in the list should be listed in the other listbox found on the first tab (enabled processors).

Below is a full working example that can be pasted in a starter WPF application

If you uncomment this line

```
_selectedProcessorsView.Filter = processorFilter;
```

in the MainWindow_VM() constructor, the processors are no longer displayed in the configuration tab.

Two main questions:

1. Why does the filtering affect both lists?
2. How can I fix this so that the enabled processors listbox on the first tab is bound to only the checked items in the second tab?

**NOTE:** The three classes at the end of my code (Config, Settings, and Processor are part of a class library that I can't modify.  The WPF app is just a UI around that library.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow_VM></local:MainWindow_VM>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="enabled processors">
                <ListBox   ItemsSource="{Binding selectedProcessorsView}"   VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=processorType}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="configuration">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=reportTypes}"   SelectedItem="{Binding selectedConfiguration}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=id, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding reportProcessors}"  SelectedItem="{Binding selectedProcessor}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Enabled"  >
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Settings.isEnabled}" ></CheckBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Processor"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=processorType, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=processorId, Mode=OneWay}"   >
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class MainWindow_VM : BindableBase
    {
        public MainWindow_VM()
        {
            reportTypes.Add(new Config()
            {
                id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Processors = new Dictionary<string, Processor>() {
                    { "Processor 1", new Processor() { processorType = "Blue" } },
                    { "Processor 2", new Processor() { processorType = "Yellow" } }
                }
            });

            reportTypes.Add(new Config()
            {
                id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Processors = new Dictionary<string, Processor>() {
                    { "Processor 3", new Processor() { processorType = "Green" } },
                    { "Processor 4", new Processor() { processorType = "Red" } }
                }
            });

            _selectedProcessorsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(reportProcessors);
            //_selectedProcessorsView.Filter = processorFilter;
        }

        public bool processorFilter(object item)
        {
            bool result = true;
            Processor p = item as Processor;

            if (p.Settings.isEnabled == false)
                result = false;

            return result;
        }

        private Config _selectedConfiguration;
        public Config selectedConfiguration
        {
            get { return _selectedConfiguration; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedConfiguration, value);

                reportProcessors.Clear();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Processor> kvp in value.Processors)
                    reportProcessors.Add(kvp.Value);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Config> reportTypes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Config>();

        public ObservableCollection<Processor> reportProcessors { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Processor>();

        private ICollectionView _selectedProcessorsView;
        public ICollectionView selectedProcessorsView
        {
            get { return _selectedProcessorsView; }
        }
    }

///These three classes below are part of a separate class library that I cannot modify

    public class Config
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Processor> Processors { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Processor
    {
        public string processorType { get; set; }
        public Settings Settings { get; set; } = new Settings() {
            isEnabled = false
        };
    }
    public class Settings
    {
        public bool isEnabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with the following approach, combined mm8's answer to my first question, with my own wrapper class that acts as a viewmodel to the Processor object (model).

Whenever a checkbox is checked or unchecked, the listviewcollection is refreshed thus updating the collection displayed in the first tab.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class MainWindow_VM : BindableBase
    {
        public MainWindow_VM()
        {
            reportTypes.Add(new Config()
            {
                id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Processors = new Dictionary<string, Processor>() {
                    { "Processor 1", new Processor() { processorType = "Blue" } },
                    { "Processor 2", new Processor() { processorType = "Yellow" } }
                }
            });

            reportTypes.Add(new Config()
            {
                id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Processors = new Dictionary<string, Processor>() {
                    { "Processor 3", new Processor() { processorType = "Green" } },
                    { "Processor 4", new Processor() { processorType = "Red" } }
                }
            });

            selectedProcessorsView = new ListCollectionView(processors);
            selectedProcessorsView.Filter = processorFilter;
        }

        public bool processorFilter(object item)
        {
            bool result = true;
            ProcessorWrapper p = item as ProcessorWrapper;

            if (p.isEnabled == false)
                result = false;

            return result;
        }

        private Config _selectedConfiguration;
        public Config selectedConfiguration
        {
            get { return _selectedConfiguration; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedConfiguration, value);

                processors.Clear();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Processor> kvp in value.Processors)
                    processors.Add(new ProcessorWrapper(kvp.Value, this.selectedProcessorsView));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Config> reportTypes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Config>();

        public ObservableCollection<ProcessorWrapper> processors { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ProcessorWrapper>();

        public ListCollectionView selectedProcessorsView { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProcessorWrapper : BindableBase
    {
        public ProcessorWrapper(Processor processor, ListCollectionView lcv)
        {
            _processor = processor;
            _lcv = lcv;
        }

        private Processor _processor;
        private ListCollectionView _lcv;

        private string _processorType;
        public string processorType
        {
            get {

                _processorType = _processor.processorType;
                return _processorType;
            }
        }

        private bool _isEnabled;
        public bool isEnabled
        {
            get {
                _isEnabled = this._processor.Settings.isEnabled;
                return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _isEnabled, value);
                this._processor.Settings.isEnabled = _isEnabled;
                _lcv.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// These classes belong to a separate class library, should not be modified.  
    /// </summary>

    public class Config
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Processor> Processors { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Processor
    {
        public string processorType { get; set; }
        public Settings Settings { get; set; } = new Settings() {
            isEnabled = false
        };
    }
    public class Settings
    {
        public bool isEnabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow_VM></local:MainWindow_VM>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="enabled processors">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding selectedProcessorsView}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=processorType}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="configuration">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=reportTypes}"   SelectedItem="{Binding selectedConfiguration}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=id, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding processors}"  SelectedItem="{Binding selectedProcessor}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Enabled"  >
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=isEnabled}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Processor"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=processorType, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the filtering affect both lists?

`{Binding reportProcessors}` and `{Binding selectedProcessorsView}` bind to the same view. When you bind to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, or any other type of source collection for that matter, you are actually binding to an automatically generated `CollectionView` and not to the actual source collection itself.

> How can I fix this so that the enabled processors listbox on the first tab is bound to only the checked items in the second tab?

Bind to two different views. But you also need to notify the view when the `isEnabled` propery is actually set to a new value. Otherwise your filter won't be updated as you check the `CheckBoxes`. The fact that you are using a `Setting` class complicates this a bit but you could add a property to the `Processor` class and live filter on this one. Both `Settings` and `Processor` need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event.

Please refer to the following sample code. It should give you the idea.

```
public class MainWindow_VM : BindableBase
{
    public MainWindow_VM()
    {
        ...

        ListCollectionView selectedProcessorsView = new ListCollectionView(reportProcessors);
        selectedProcessorsView.LiveFilteringProperties.Add(nameof(Processor.IsEnabled));
        selectedProcessorsView.IsLiveFiltering = true;
        selectedProcessorsView.Filter = processorFilter;

        _selectedProcessorsView = selectedProcessorsView;
    }
    ...
 }

public class Processor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string processorType { get; set; }

    public Settings Settings { get; set; } = new Settings()
    {
        isEnabled = false
    };

    public bool IsEnabled => Settings.isEnabled;

    public Processor()
    {
        Settings.PropertyChanged += Settings_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Settings_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsEnabled));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Settings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool isEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set { _isEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I was trying to avoid turning my Setting and Processor classes into a kind of view model, because they are actually part of a separate library.  Could there be a way to get the checkbox to trigger something in the existing view model which collects the checked items?

Comment: I am not sue what you mean but if your view models don't raise change notifications you will have to re-create the collection view each time a CheckBox is checked.

Comment: What about DataTrigger? to trigger some view model property to update a collection? Or maybe I'm thinking about this in the wrong way, I could just run a method on the selection changed event for the tab control and when user selects the first tab, just query the object and get all the ones that are selected and put them into a separate observable collection that is bound to the first listbox.

Comment: or maybe i just need to update the new collection view to update itself when the user checks a checkbox, just another idea, not sure if possible yet

Comment: A DataTrigger won't work unless you raise the PropertyChanged event...I have given you an example of how to solve your issue. What's your current issue?

Comment: Ok, the solution you posted involves modifying a class library that I don't have access to.  The WPF app is just a wrapper around that.  I will add comment to the code in my post to clarify that

Comment: Create your own wrapper classes in your WPF app that wraps the class library classes then. Should be simple.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for...?

Comment: an idea on how to solve the second part of my problem that doesn't involve modifying the source code of the library classes I indicated in my update.  .

Comment: Processor and Settings are wrapper classes in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174812/discussion-between-erotavlas-and-mm8).